# What is user_ini.filename & user_ini.cache_ttl in php?

Tags: php

I am new to php and found these two names of files on php.net manual

1. user_ini.filename
2. user_ini.cache_ttl

Can any one tell what are these files. I already know about php.ini file that it is php configuration file but don't know about these two files that for what purpose and why these files are used.

**Can any one tell ?**

Comment: Does this help: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: I think you didn't read out the question i asked carefully. I got these two file names from php.net and didn't get why these are used. This story is begin from php.net....

Comment: That page explains it on the first line: to allow per-directory PHP configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose is to allow directory-specific PHP configuration. You set `user_ini.filename` to the name of a file to look for in the directory of the PHP script (and its all the parent directories up to the document root if necessary). If the file is found, it will be treated as an additional `.ini` file, so it can override settings in the main `php.ini`.

To avoid having to reread these files every time, PHP keeps the contents in a cache. `user_ini.cache_ttl` tells it how often to refresh the cache.

More details can be found in the comments in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php).

Comment: Thank you so much. I got you

Comment: Note that this means there will be a delay between changing your settings and the change taking effect; by default this is 5 minutes. This can be very frustrating, especially if you’re experimenting with settings.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in the ini, use the url to the description of configuration items.
ex.

```
; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name = PHPSESSID
```